# ASP.net, C#4, WebMethod, JQuery-Ajax, JSON data - Retrive the return?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, json, jquery, c#-4.0

My jQuery performs it's action with success, I know, because I get authenticated with the server, but I've got a problem accessing the return data. I've tried added the `.d` to solutions found on Google..

JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "something.asmx/Login",
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'a': '" + a.val() + "', 'p': '" + p.val() + "'}",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    cache: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    error: function () {
         //Not needed here    
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg.d == '1') {
            //Something not need for question
        }
        else {
            //Not needed here neither.
        }
    }
});
```

And my Webmethod (`something.cs`):

```
private string res;

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string Login(string a, string p) {
    if (SecurityTools.GainAccess(a, p)) res = "1";
    else res = "0";
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(res);
}
```

Comment: Use a json serializer to create your `data` string instead of building it manually.

Comment: To find out what gets sent back from the server, add `console.log(msg);` to your callback and then execute the function while Firebug is open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer, I had to write:

```
 if (msg.d == '"1"')
```

both with `JavascriptSerializer` and the `Newtonstof.Json` namespace.